# how to remove only meaning less words in sentence using NPL or Spacy in python example : fvbfxcfbs, #$%$#$$##$, sdhsjkbnfsgfdf

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy-3

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize

words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
sent = 'my name is vallem balu fvbfxcfbs gvcx 2124326456 4554 @#@%$@!%^$#@%$ from Andhra Pradesh i was working software engineer'

data=''.join(e for e in sent if (e.isalnum() or e.isspace()))
print(data)
sent =" ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(str(data)) \
         if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
print(sent)
```

output:

my name is vallem balu fvbfxcfbs gvcx 2124326456 4554  from Andhra Pradesh i was working software engineer

my name is balu 2124326456 4554 from i was working engineer

how to get below full sentence:
my name is vallem balu  2124326456 4554 from Andhra Pradesh i was working software engineer

Comment: You need to define "meaningless words" and check for them. One common way to is to say any word not in a particular dictionary (list of words) is meaningless. spaCy does not provide a list of words like that.

Comment: list words create not possible because a lot of words any pre-trained models